# create lambda using .env file

Tags: shell, environment-variables, aws-lambda

I have four lambda to be created. my folder structure is as below

```
folder1ForLambda1
  index.js
  package.json
  .env
folder2ForLambda2
  index.js
  package.json
  .env
folder3ForLambda3
  index.js
  package.json
  .env
folder4ForLambda4
  index.js
  package.json
  .env
build.sh
```

I have build script for all the lambdas in build.sh file. I would like to use respective .env file to set environment variables for each lambda.

```
pushd ./folder1ForLambda1
aws lambda create-function \
  --function-name $PREFIX-$MODULE_NAME \
  --runtime nodejs6.10 \
  --handler "index.handler" \
  --code S3Bucket=$BUCKET_NAME,S3Key=$ZIP_NAME.zip \
  --environment Variables="" \
  --memory-size 512 \
  --timeout 5 \
  --publish
popd
```

I have this code for each lambda.
How do I use .env to set environment variables?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [source](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) to read environment variables from a file (*.env* in your case)

```
source ./folder1ForLambda1/.env
```

**Update**

Try this:

```
--environment Variables="{`cat .env | xargs | sed 's/ /,/g'`}" \
```

- Using [cat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html) to feed *xargs*
- Using [xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) to get the variables from *stdin*, output looks like `k1=v11 k2=v33`
- Using [sed](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) to replace spaces with commas separate variables `k1=v11 k2=v33`

So your script will look like

```
pushd ./folder1ForLambda1
aws lambda create-function \
--function-name $PREFIX-$MODULE_NAME \
--runtime nodejs6.10 \
--handler "index.handler" \
--code S3Bucket=$BUCKET_NAME,S3Key=$ZIP_NAME.zip \
--environment Variables="{`cat .env | xargs | sed 's/ /,/g'`}" \
--memory-size 512 \
--timeout 5 \
--publish
popd
```

Comment: And how am I going to use them in `--environment Variables=""` This syntax?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question at the beginning, please see updates.

Comment: aws lambda create-function accepts `--environment` option. But update-function-code does not. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

aws lambda create-function accepts `--environment` option. But update-function-code does not.

Instead, use update-function-configuration to create/update environment variables.

This command chain (below) handles .env files that include comment lines and values that include blanks.

Input:

```
# this is a comment 
ABC=1
DEF="A blank is included"
```

Command line:

```
aws lambda update-function-configuration \
--function-name API_Request_Builder_Gateway \
--environment Variables="{`cat .env | sed '/^#/d' | \
sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/,/g'`}"
```

sed tip: SO answer